# Angular/2 | Filter async stream

Tags: angular

I'm passing data to a child component using the async pipe but I wish to filter the data by the value of "mimetype". However, when I add my filter I do not pick up any new objects added to the stream. For example; the following works perfectly

```
<asset-list [assets]="assets$ | async"></asset-list>
```

inside the child component I am looping through the assets to display a list. However, if I add my filter pipe for example

```
<asset-list [assets]="assets$ | async | imageFilter"></asset-list>
```

I no longer pick up any changes to the stream. My pipe reads as follows:

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'imageFilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class AssetImagesPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(assets: any[] ) {

        var images = [];

        for( let i in assets ) {

            if( assets[i].mimetype.substring(0,5) == 'image' )
            {
                images.push( assets[i] );
            }
        }

        return images;
    }
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible ways:

Set your Pipe to `pure: false` (https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes)

or use it before that async-pipe..

Impure-pipe:

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'imageFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class AssetImagesPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(assets: any[] ) {
      if (!assets || !assets.length) return [];
      return assets.filter(...);
    }
}
```

Before async-pipe:

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'imageFilter$'
})
export class AssetImagesAsyncPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(assets$: Observable<any[]>) {
      if (!assets$) return undefined;
      return assets$.map(assets => assets.filter(...));
    }
}
```

See my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Q2Yw2TjdpGqA4dWBxfZ0?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, superb answer. I went with option two because impure pipes appear to have a large overhead.

Comment: any other way for some repeated value max 5 times then create new array and remove that value from array? I HAVE THIS KIND OF ARRAY: ["info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition"]